# HTML Video Ended Event Not Triggering in Backbone View

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, html5-video

I'm trying to trigger an `ended` event on a html video tag. The problem is that it seems to be calling the ended event as soon as the page is refreshed and not when the video actually ends.

Any ideas how I can get an event to trigger when the video ends and not when the page first loads?

```
events: 
  "ended #video": console.log "video ended"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is the way to go:

```
onShow: ->
      if @model.get('videoQuestion')
        console.log "show"
        @$('#video').bind("ended", ->
            console.log "test"
          )
```